# Pheatmap row annotation coloring for multiple groups R

Tags: r, pheatmap

Dear all I have a dataframe such as-

| genes | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.5 | 2.7 | 7.8 | 6.1 | cluster1 |
| B | 1.2 | 2.1 | 7.6 | 6.3 | cluster2 |
| C | 10.11 | 12.1 | 3.6 | 5.3 | cluster2 |
| D | 0.1 | 2.15 | 0.06 | 0.05 | cluster3 |

I have 82 such clusters and 116 such genes.
If it was just a annotating and coloring 3-10 clusters
I could easily do-

```
library(randomcoloR)
n <- 6
palette1 <- distinctColorPalette(n)
palette1
#[1] "#D043DE" "#B39F92" "#7BCDDC" "#6F45E5" "#A1E849" "#DFDDA5"
ann_color = list("hubID"=c("cluster1"="#D043DE","cluster2"= "#B39F92", "cluster3"="#7BCDDC" ,"cluster4"= "#6F45E5", "cluster5"= "#A1E849", "cluster6"= "#DFDDA5"))
```

But how do I do the same for 82 clusters. Also I don't think that assigning 82 different colors on a pheatmap could be a little too eye-stressing.
Can anyone help me with getting a range of blues or grays and assigning it uniquely to these clusters?
I tried to do something like this-

```
    n <-  82
palette1 <- distinctColorPalette(n)
palette1
annoationdf <- data.frame(hubIDs, palette1)
annodflst <- list("cluster"=t(annoationdf))
annodflst
pheatmap(as.matrix(mat1), cluster_cols = FALSE,cluster_rows = FALSE, scale = "row", main = "Expression", show_rownames = F,
     cellwidth = 3, cellheight = 3, treeheight_row = 3, treeheight_col = 3, fontsize = 3, annotation_row = annotation_row, annotation_colors = annodflst )
```

But it throws me an error:

```
Error: elements in `col` should be named vectors.
```

I am not sure at this point what I could try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by removing NA values from my objects.

Comment: The OP does not mention the presence of NAs, nor are the present in the example table provided. NAs _might_ be present and your suggestion _might_ solve the OP's issue, but there's no way of knowing.